# Why does this xpath match this text node?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0, dita-ot

Why does this xpath from dita-ot

```
"*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/title ')]
```

match the text node "Getting started"?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.1/OS/dtd/concept.dtd">
<concept id="mobileapp_gs" rev="3">
    <title>Getting started</title>
    <conbody>        
    </conbody>
</concept>
```

Regards
Conteh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DTD can provide default attribute values.  This processing happens before applying any XPath expressions.  The DTD you reference here is somewhat complex, but if I run an identity XSLT stylesheet over it (take the input, fill in any defaults from the DTD, and just copy it out) the preprocessed input looks more like (lightly formatted)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<concept xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/"
         id="mobileapp_gs"
         rev="3"
         ditaarch:DITAArchVersion="1.1"
         domains="(topic ui-d) (topic hi-d) (topic pr-d) (topic sw-d)                          (topic ut-d) (topic indexing-d)"
         class="- topic/topic concept/concept ">
    <title class="- topic/title ">Getting started</title>
    <conbody class="- topic/body  concept/conbody ">        
    </conbody>
</concept>
```

After this step, the `<concept />` element more obviously has a `class` attribute containing `topic/topic`, with a child element with a `class` attribute containing `topic/title`.